# В таблицах Mysql вместо русских букв символы

Tags: php, mysql

Почему в таблицах бд Mysql вместо русских букв отображаются символы такого вида:

```
d0a1d0bfd0b8d181d0bed0ba20d183d187d0b5d0bdd0b8d0bad0bed0b2 - что на самом деле "Список учеников"
```

Кодировка: utf8_bin
При выводе на страницу все отлично работает, но в самой базе такие символы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каким клиентом для работы с БД MySQL Вы пользуетесь?

Есть предположение что проблема в установке кодировки для соединения `SET NAMES`. Устанавливается кодировка соединения обычно где-то в настройках.

**UPD:** В [инете](https://qa.mandriva.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59446) пишут что это баг, и его пофиксили в версии 3.3.3

Comment: Через XAMPP(phpMyAdmin).
У меня стоит в файле подключения с базой 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте кодировку `cp_1251_general_ci`. Проверьте также, не стоит ли там случайно хеширование `sh1` или `md5`.

Comment: Если данные были бы зашифрованы через MD5, то об обратном преобразовании не могло бы быть и речи.

Comment: чередование d0 и d1 указывают на то, что это русские буквы utf-8 в 16-ричной записи, а не хэш-функция какая либо.